# Implement primitive recursive factorial in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, primitive

I am currently trying to implement primitive recursive factorial in Haskell.
I'm using the function recNat, as a recursor. That is:

```
recNat :: a -> (Nat -> a -> a) -> Nat -> a
recNat a _ Zero = a
recNat a h (Succ n) = h n (recNat a h n)
```

This is our attempt, but can't quite figure out what's wrong

```
factR :: Nat -> Nat
factR Zero = Succ Zero
factR (Succ m) = recNat (Succ m) (\ _ y -> y) (factR m)
```

I was also trying to implement the exponential function, but it seems even more confusing.

Comment: Do you want multiplication (as stated in your question) or factorial (as stated in your title)?

Comment: factorial! My mistake

Comment: Your lambda ignores the first argument, so the `recNat` invocation will always return `(Succ m)`. You need a way of piling the `Nat` increments on the recursion stack if you want to have a primitive recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement a factorial, we can implement a function for multiplication. For the multiplication function, we need the addition function

```hs
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add a Zero     = a
add a (Succ b) = Succ (add a b)

mul :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mul a Zero     = Zero
mul a (Succ b) = add a (mul a b)
```

Then the factorial function just comes down to:

```hs
fac :: Nat -> Nat
fac Zero = Succ Zero
fac (Succ a) = mul (Succ a) (fac a)
```